# Return Value from jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to return a value from a completed jQuery Ajax call. However, instead of the JSON data, I am receiving back "undefined." How can I modify my code to get the JSON data instead of undefined?

```
function callback(data) {
    return data;
}

var xv = jQuery.ajax( {
    url: 'http://www.domain.com/json.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success.'); // This is alerted.
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('File could not be processed.'); // This is not alerted.
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        callback(data);
    }
});

console.log(callback()); // Getting "undefined" here instead of data.
```

Comment: I don't get it, you're calling `callback` without a parameter, `data` of course is undefined.

Comment: Also the `complete` handler's first parameter is a `jqXHR`, not data. Data is passed as first parameter only to `success`.

Comment: AJAX is async by default, you have your data only when you get it, that's in your `success` callback. Do a `sync` call, or use your data inside your success function.

Comment: Your `callback` method returns `data`, but where it is invoked in the `complete` "callback" function, the result is not used. In addition, in the line `console.log(callback())`, you are invoking the method `callback` without any argument. That line is useless, by the way; if you want to output `data` to the console, do it in the `callback` method or in the `complete` callback function.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is async by default, you have your data only when you get it, that's in your success callback. Do a sync call, or use your data inside your success function.

Your code should look like this instead:

```
function doWithJson(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
var xv = jQuery.ajax( {
    url: 'http://www.domain.com/json.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        doWithJson(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('File could not be processed.');
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        /* Remove overlay */
    }
});
```

Comment: Bingo. That was it! Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually storing `data` anywhere.  All you do is reflect back whatever is given to you, just like Sterling said

I would modify it like so:

```
var globalData;
function(callback){
  globalData = data;
}
```

Then `console.log(globalData)` and you can see the result